# Alternating Markov process

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process

Given the situation:

- When Bob enters the room and the light is off, he turns it on with $P = 1/2$
  when it is on, he does nothing.
- When Alice enters the room with light on, she turns it off with $P =1/2$ and when the light is off, she turns it on with $P= 1/4$
- Bob and Alice alternatively enter and leave the room after each other many times

Find the P the light is on just after
- Alice enters
- Bob enters

I've retrieved the long run probabilities of both and know that the state $t+n$ is $Mb^n * Ma^n * state(t)$  where $Ma$ = Alice's Markov matrix - although I don't know how to define how many or how to equalize the long run probabilities when alternating?

Is it (for just after Alice enters) - the Ma* Bob's long run probabilities $(pi1,pi2)$?

Comment: What about defining a 4-state Markov chain?

Comment: Or collapse it to a 2-state Markov chain but sampled every 2 steps?  So the transition probability matrix $P = P_AP_B$.

Comment: I do not know what you mean by "the state $t+n$ is $M_b^n M_a^nstate(t)$."  Do the $M_a$ and $M_b$ matrices commute? In general we cannot guarantee $(M_bM_a)^n = M_b^nM_a^n$.

Comment: I think you mean that if $t$ is a time when Bob enters the room, and if $[\pi_1(t) \: \pi_2(t)]$ is the probability distribution for what Bob sees, then $[\pi_1(t+2n) \: \pi_2(t+2n)] = [\pi_1(t) \: \pi_2(t)](M_bM_a)^n$.

Comment: Thanks Michael. Well yes, it's not guaranteed that this is known, I'm just trying to understand how compute the P in the long run..

Comment: So, now do you know how to do it? If you treat the system sampled every 2 steps?  If not, do this:  Draw two states (ON, OFF) on your paper, these are the states seen by Bob.  Now compute the 4 different transition probabilities associated with 2-steps.  So $P_{ON,ON}$ is the probability that Bob sees ON two steps later, given that he sees ON now.  So you can draw an arrow on your paper from ON to ON and label it with thise probability $P_{ON,ON}$. And $P_{ON,OFF}$, $P_{OFF,ON}$, $P_{OFF,OFF}$ are defined similarly.

Comment: Ok...so would I use conditional P to calculate each of these 4 elements?

Comment: Let $a$ denote the probability that the light is on when Alice enters the room and $b$ the probability that the light is on when Bob enters the room, then, conditioning on the state of the room one step of time earlier, one sees that $$b=a\cdot\tfrac12+(1-a)\cdot\tfrac14\qquad a=b\cdot1+(1-b)\cdot\tfrac12$$ hence $$a=\tfrac57\qquad b=\tfrac37.$$

Answer (score 2):

In order to make the entire process be Markov, you can raise the dimension, and consider a four state chain: the states are $(A,1),(A,0),(B,1),(B,0)$. (This is a common theme: you can increase the dimension to take away memory effects, or reduce the dimension at the cost of adding memory effects.) The first component represents "Alice will come in next/Bob will come in next". The second component represents "the light is on/the light is off". So for instance $(A,1)$ is "Alice is coming in next and the light is on". Then your transition matrix for this chain is

$$P=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1/2 & 1/2 \\
0 & 0 & 1/4 & 3/4 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1/2 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

For instance the second row reads "if Alice is about to come in and the light is off, then at the next step, with probability 1/4, Bob is about to come in and the light is on, and with probability 3/4, Bob is about to come in and the light is off."

Here I am using the convention that $P_{ij}$ is the probability to go from $i$ to $j$, so that if the distribution is currently the row vector $q$ then at the next step it is $qP$.

Now a full step where Alice goes in and Bob goes in evolves the distribution according to $P^2$. So given an initial distribution $q$ which is confined to $\{ (A,1),(A,0) \}$ (meaning that Alice will always come in first), calculate $q_A=\lim_{n \to \infty} q P^{2n}$. This will be the limiting distribution that Alice sees. Then calculate $q_B=q_A P$; this will be the limiting distribution that Bob sees.

Importantly, the fact that the first component of this process is a "deterministic oscillator" (always flipping back and forth between $A$ and $B$) causes $P$ to have an eigenvalue of $-1$. This causes $q_A$ and $q_B$ to not simply be the same. If Alice came in twice in a row even one in every million visits, $q_A$ and $q_B$ would be equal (but the convergence would be very slow).

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_t$ be the probability that the light is on, and $y_t$ be the probability that the light is off, before step $t$.

If Alice enters the room:
$$x_{t+1} = \frac 12 x_t + \frac 14 y_t$$
$$y_{t+1} = \frac 12 x_t + \frac 34 y_t$$

If Bob enters the room:

$$x_{t+1} = \frac 12 y_t + x_t$$
$$y_{t+1} = \frac 12 y_t$$

When Alice enters the room, $[x_{t+1} ~~ y_{t+1}] = [x_{t} ~~ y_{t}]A$ for some matrix $A$.

When Bob enters the room, $[x_{t+1} ~~ y_{t+1}] = [x_{t} ~~ y_{t}]B$ for some matrix $B$.

You want to find $A$ and $B$ and use that to find $[x_{\infty} ~~ y_{\infty}]$.